# Youtube URL to Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, youtube

I am running ticketing software with the ability to manipulate CSS and JS for customization and I need to convert a video URL to an iframe. I am currently using this code:

```
 $('#wiki-page-content').contents().each(function() {
// Skip non text nodes.
if (this.nodeType !== 3) {
    return true;
}
// Grab text
var matches = this.data.match(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g);

if (!matches) {
    return true;
}
var iframe = $('<iframe width="420" height="345" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen />', {
    src: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + matches[1]
});
iframe.insertAfter(this);
$(this).remove();});
```

Now, the problem is when somebody puts a URL inside a WIKI page by using a text editor, it wraps a `<P></P>` tag around it. Is this causing a problem? How can I get over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag has noteType equals 1. Try something like this:

```
$('#wiki-page-content').contents().each(function() {
    // Skip non text nodes.
    var text;

    switch (this.nodeType) {
        case 3:
            text = this.data;
            break;
        case 1:
            text = this.innerHTML; // or this.textContent
            break;
        default:
            return true;
    }

    // Grab text
    var matches = text.match(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g);

    if (!matches) {
        return true;
    }
    var iframe = $('<iframe width="420" height="345" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen />', {
        src: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + matches[1]
    });
    iframe.insertAfter(this);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: didn't work it made everything inside that class disappear